# Any idea why MSBuild would suddenly start performing code analysis on other projects in my solution?

Tags: msbuild, code-analysis, fxcop, stylecop

I've been busy turning on code analysis for one of our solutions. On Friday everything was going well.

I had added the following to *one* of our csproj files:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>ca.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And spend some time on Friday working through the warnings, like this:

1. Disable all warnings in ca.ruleset
2. Enable one
3. Fix all instances
4. Re-build the solution to verify the fix
5. GOTO 2

This had been working really well. I came in this morning and picked up where I left off, except that when I got to step 4 (rebuilding the solution), I suddenly had 3k+ warnings from our unit test project.

I'm not sure why code analysis is now being applied to this other project and I can't seem to disable it.

Some observations:

- The csproj file of the unit test project has no references to either FxCop or StyleCop.
- Nor does it refer in any way to ruleset.ca
- `dotnet clean` doesn't help
- Checking out another branch (one without any CA turned on) stops analysis for both projects (as expected), but switching back results in them both being analysed again.
- I'm using VS Code, so can't play around with any of the GUI settings that people seem (according to my Googling) to suggest for CA issues
- My .sln file doesn't appear to have any reference to CA at all - it's just the usual project and build definitions.

I'm beginning to think this must be an issue with MSBuild.

Has anyone ever seen this before? What was the fix?

---

**Update:** Have [filed a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/3983) with the MSBuild team.

As per the bug report, this seems to be a general MSBuild thing and unrelated to any particular environment. For now I'm just going to add a blanket `ignore` ruleset, but it's hardly ideal.

Comment: Package references of an assembly can propagate to all projects that depend on that assembly. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5715

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. So that might be the "why?" Any idea how I'd fix it / work around it?

Comment: hm but build and analyzers don't flow across p2ps usually (default for PrivateAssets). Does it also happen on command line builds or inside VS only?

Comment: @MartinUllrich Sadly, also in command line builds. I just tried in CMD and Git Bash.

Comment: @MartinUllrich Just tried on our CI system too - same thing :(

Comment: [Even members of the VS team at Microsoft don't always know what MS Build is doing](https://twitter.com/jaredpar/status/1069695021715079168)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Haha! Thanks - makes me feel a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround via my bug report.

[Nick Guerra suggested](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/968#issuecomment-410319090) adding `PrivateAssets="All"` to the `PackageReference` statement in the csproj file of my main project.

In other words, for me, this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.6.2" />
<PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.0.2" />
```

Became this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.6.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.0.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

A quick `dotnet clean && dotnet build` later, and all those warnings vanish!

---

It seems as though this attribute enforces what should already be the default behaviour: that analysers should be treated as being private to the project to which they are directly added. [Relevant bug.](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6279)